# I am trying to extract names of the reviewers in steam , but I am getting empty list , where am I wrong?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, steam

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import lxml
import openpyxl as op
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

# from lxml


html_text = 'https://store.steampowered.com/app/354400/Tadpole_Treble/'
# wb = op.load_workbook(
#     'https://1drv.ms/x/s!Aiw1ZpHhhvdugd0Z_eEBU_KzDlxiuA?e=cWevHn')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path='C:/Users/atif/Downloads/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get(html_text)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)


names = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="persona_name"]/a')


print(len(names))

for name in names:
    print(name.text)

# body = soup.body

# titles = headers.find_all('a', class_='title fw500 ellipsis')
# for h in headers:
#     # title = h.find('a', class_='title fw500 ellipsis').text
#     print(h.a['href'])

# a_links = body.find_all("a")
driver.close()
```

> **this is the answer I am getting**

> [20380:14344:0416/154733.584:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)]
> [15:47:33.584] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1072 Getting
> Default Adapter failed.

> 0   < = **Result showing zero**

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code is correct but the element is not loaded at that time. That's why you are getting empty list. The reviews are loading once you scroll down the page to the end. I have tried the below code and it works for me. Do let me know if it works for you or not.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get('https://store.steampowered.com/app/354400/Tadpole_Treble')
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
sleep(5)

ReviewersNames = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class=\"persona_name\"]/a")

for reviewer in ReviewersNames:
    print(reviewer.text)
```

**Note - you can also use explicit wait above.**

Please mark it as answer if it resolves your problem.